# How does one specify where to redirect output from a bash script, in systemd script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, systemd, logs

I have a command in bash script that runs my custom application:

```
./my_app --config ./cfg >> my_app.log 2>>my_app.err
```

And I want to wrap this into a systemd service. I've done this so far:

```
[Unit]
Description=my_app
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/user123/my_app_dir/my_app --config cfg
Restart=on-abort
WorkingDirectory=/home/user123/my_app_dir
SyslogIdentifier=my_app
User=my_user

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

How do I have to convert those 2 parts that redirect output into the logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
StandardOutput=file:/path/to/log1
StandardError=file:/path/to/log2
```

See [official manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html). This will create a new file or overwrite old one, so maybe you want `StandardOutput=append:/path/to/log1` in order to keep old logs.